# NPE with Artemis core client version 2.19 and server version 2.16

Tags: activemq-artemis

Updating spring boot version is bringing a new Artemis client version (2.19), but my server is still on 2.16 (might be updated in the future)

Currently I have a NPE problem on the ActiveMQSession:

```java
if ((!subResponse.isExists() || !Objects.equals(subResponse.getAddress(), dest.getSimpleAddress()) || !Objects.equals(subResponse.getFilterString(), coreFilterString)) && !subResponse.isConfigurationManaged()) {
```

Because the subResponse.isConfigurationManaged() is null.
Is it possible to make version 2.16 of the server return this value?
Is there any compatibility guide between client and server?

Thanks

Comment: Looking at the main branch looks like the problem is fixed (https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/main/artemis-jms-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/client/ActiveMQSession.java) when will a new release will be provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you're upgrading in the opposite direction of what is usually done. Typically the broker is upgraded *before* the clients (since it's easier to upgrade one server than potentially hundreds or thousands of clients). We have a good number of compatibility tests to ensure that older clients work with newer brokers, but we have far fewer tests to ensure that newer clients work with older brokers (i.e. your situation).

In any case, the NPE you're hitting has already [been resolved](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/pull/3892) and will be included in the next release (i.e. 2.21.0). There currently is no schedule for this release as the previous release (i.e. 2.20.0) was in late December less than a month ago now.

Until the next release you have two main options:

1. Downgrade your client back to a compatible version.
2. Patch & build the client yourself. This should be a fairly simple process as the changes are quite small. Then you can build a custom release of your own using `mvn clean install -Prelease -DskipTests`.

Comment: Downgrade with gradle is not easy task. Trying to upgrade broker instead. The only problem I found is with hawtio. From release notes seems it was upgraded also some jmx roles issue was fixed. I have it integrated with keycloak (https://hawt.io/docs/keycloak-integration/#jetty). But with 2.20.0 jolokia is returning 403. Any hint on what might be the problem? on UI just see: ERROR: User not authorized to access attribute: AcknowledgeAttempts (class java.lang.SecurityException).

Comment: I've never used Gradle so I can't speak to that point. Also, I have very little experience with Keycloak so I can't address that point either. I recommend you either start a new thread on the [ActiveMQ users mailing](https://activemq.apache.org/contact) list or create a new Stack Overflow question. It's different enough from your original issue that it needs to be treated independently.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm trying to retrieve more details. Seems problem start at 2.17.0 and on 2.16.0 jolokia is giving 403, but all operations on hawtio work. Thanks